# Topology Manager installation script can't find Tablespace

Tags: web8, 2011-sp1, oracle-12c

We are currently upgrading a 2011 SP1 Hr2 env. to Web 8.1.1. When we did this in our last environment, this went without problems, but now when we are trying to install the Topology Manager Database we get following error:

```
Failed to execute query: ORA-00959: tablespace '<name>' does not exist
Query: ALTER USER <ttm user> DEFAULT TABLESPACE <name> TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP PROFILE DEFAULT
...
```

The strange thing is that, when we look into the oracle database, the tablespace does exist. Last time we did this upgrade (same client, same database server, now is just a new layer in the DTAP) there was no problem at all.

Anyone has any idea?

kr,

Thomas

Comment: Very weird. Only thing that comes to mind is that the current user doesn't have access to it somehow? or that you're connecting to the wrong database (happens more often than we'd wish)

Comment: The admin account which is used for this, is the same as the one for the CM upgrade. The ttm user is also created by the Install script itself and last the rights were right from the first time, but we will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently we used the wrong namespace due to the database setup not being default.